# How can I make an add or remove input fields in react

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to create a button function that can Add or Remove input fields instead of duplicate it like this:

```
  <ul>
    <li>
      <input
        type="text"
        name="rule_one"
        placeholder="Rule 1"
        defaultValue={rule_one}
        onChange={handleChange}
      />
    </li>
    <li>
      <input
        placeholder="Rule 2"
        type="text"
        name="rule_second"
        defaultValue={rule_second}
        onChange={handleChange}
      />
    </li>
    <li>
      <input
        placeholder="Rule 3"
        type="text"
        name="rule_third"
        defaultValue={rule_third}
        onChange={handleChange}
      />
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div className="team-agreement-add-rule">
    <button type="submit" onClick={handleSubmit}>
      <Save />
    </button>
  </div>
```

How can I achieve that function ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way could be to initialize a state as an empty array,

```js
const [inputs, setInputs] = useState([]);
```

each time the button is clicked an object could be added in the array:

```js
<button onClick={() => addInputs()}>Add input</button>
```

```js
const addInputs = () => {
  setInputs([...inputs, { name: `rule-${inputs.length + 1}` }]);
};
```

To render it you'll need to do map the inputs array, like this:

```js
{inputs.map((input) => (
  <div>
    <label>{input.name}</label>
    <input name={input.name} style={{ margin: "10px" }} />
  </div>
))}
```

I'll share you a code example in codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/dynamic-inputs-0k46q?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Quick question: in my backend nodejs can I write it like this ??? `const rules = [];
  for (let i = 0; i <= 4; i++) {
    rules.push([req.body.rule_`${i}`]);
  }`

Comment: It would be better if you avoid that for loop in your back-end, what about just sending the array with your rule's information?

Comment: And how can I appear the rule that already exist on my web site? Or I just have to click add every time?

Comment: I would send the entire array to the back end and save it

Comment: Yea. But how can I make the input appear when we already have data for that one ?

Comment: You can add a value property to the object: ```[...inputs, { name: `rule-${inputs.length + 1}` value: 'myValue'}]```